# System service privilege to get process information in Windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-7, pid

I am trying to use system service privilege to get the title of a window and its process name and process ID in Windows 7, but this fails.

How can I use open process to get process information via system service privilege?

Comment: 1. What is "system service privilege"? 2. What you do mean by "fails"? 3. What is "open process"? Are you trying to get process information from a window or a process handle?

Answer (score 0):

To get other process info, you must enable `SeDebugPrivilege` for your program.

This code will enable it for you:

```
{
    int             err             = 0;
    int             result              = 0;
    HANDLE          token               = NULL;
    HANDLE          proc_handle         = NULL;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES        priv;

    /*Get the open process handle to the process*/
    proc_handle = GetCurrentProcess ();

    /* Get a token for this process.*/
    result = OpenProcessToken (proc_handle, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &token);
    if (! result)
    {
    /* return failure */
    }

    /* Get the LUID for the SeDebugPrivilege privilege.*/
    result = LookupPrivilegeValue (NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME,
        &priv.Privileges[0].Luid);
    if (! result)
    {
    err = qerr_win32toq (GetLastError ());
    printf("LookupPrivilegeValue failed with err: %d", err);

    goto out;
    }

    priv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    priv.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    result = AdjustTokenPrivileges (token, FALSE, &priv, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)
        NULL, 0);
    if (! result)
    {
    err = qerr_win32toq (GetLastError ());
    printf ("AdjustTokenPrivilege failed with err: %d", err);

    goto out;
    }

out:
    if (token)
    CloseHandle (token);

    return err;
}
```

Comment: If the OP is really running his program as a service, then this answer isn't relevant, because services running as `SYSTEM` have `SeDebugPrivilege` enabled by default.